# Asp.net Core, set multiple selected values in Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

So, I am trying to create a multi-select dropdown list and I want to set some default selected values in it. 
I get the values and store them in an array of strings containing the values in each one.
 I tried to set them as 1 string and it didn't work, tried setting them as an array of strings and it didn't work as well.

Here is the code:

```
<select name="FacultyList" multiple class="sel form-control" asp-for="Faculties" 
id="uniFaculties" asp-items="@(new SelectList(facultyList,"Name","Name",@selectedFaculties))">
</select>
```

**facultyList** is a list of values I get from and api.  
**selectedFaculties** is an array of strings that contains the selected values.

**Note:** I'm using the Chosen jQuery library as well if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `MultiSelectList` that you can use for this:

```
new MultiSelectList(facultyList, "Name", "Name", @selectedFaculties)
```

I just noticed from your code that you're using `asp-for` on the `select`. When doing that, the selected values you pass to either `SelectList` or `MultiSelectList` will be ignored. The reason is because it's expecting the selected values to be in the `Faculties` property that you're binding to. In case you run into that, here is a working example for you.

### View

```
<select name="FacultyList" multiple class="sel form-control" asp-for="SelectedFaculties"
    id="uniFaculties" asp-items="@(new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableFaculties, "Name", "Name"))">
</select>
```

### Controller

```
public IActionResult Faculty()
{
    var vm = new FacultyViewModel
    {
        AvailableFaculties = new List<Faculty>
        {
            new Faculty
            {
                Name = "Arts"
            },
            new Faculty
            {
                Name = "Science"
            },
            new Faculty
            {
                Name = "Mathematics"
            }
        },
        SelectedFaculties = new List<string> { "Arts", "Mathematics" }
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

This will select `Arts` and `Mathematics`. Notice that the selected values are coming from the same property that we're binding the `select` to using `asp-for`, and that we're no longer passing selected values to the `MultiSelectList` directly.