# Net Core - Select2 Set Selected Value

Tags: asp.net-core, select, jquery-select2

I have an edit page with razor page. I want the selected values ​​in the database in select2 to be selected in select2. For this reason, I am trying to loop selected values ​​and make them selected for select2. But this administration is not working.

```
<div class="mb-3" data-select2-id="21">
                            <select asp-for="SelectedCities" asp-items="ViewBag.CityPrices as SelectList" id="selected-cities" class="multiple-select select2-hidden-accessible" data-placeholder="Şehir Seçiniz" multiple="" data-select2-id="21" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
                        </div>
```

here is my script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

        @foreach (var packageCity in Model.PackageCities)
        {
           <text>
         $('#selected-cities').val('@packageCity.CityPrice.PriceId');
            $('#selected-cities').trigger('change');
            </text>
        }
  
</script>
```

Comment: No need to do it with JavaScript. Use [MultiSelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.multiselectlist?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Check [How can I create a SelectList with multiple selected values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839760/how-can-i-create-a-selectlist-with-multiple-selected-values) and [Asp.net Core, set multiple selected values in Razor Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081644/asp-net-core-set-multiple-selected-values-in-razor-page)

Comment: this is not the solution for me. i have to do this with javascript for select2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to set selected values in a select list:

Models:

```cs
public class Fruit
{
    public int FruitId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class DemoViewModel
{
    public List<int> SelectedFruit { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

`HomeController.cs`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // all items that should be in your select list
    var fruitList = new List<Fruit>
    {
        new Fruit { FruitId = 1, Name = "Banana" },
        new Fruit { FruitId = 2, Name = "Orange" },
        new Fruit { FruitId = 3, Name = "Apple" },
        new Fruit { FruitId = 4, Name = "Kiwi" },
    };

    // get from database the ids of the items that should be selected
    var selectedFruit = new List<int> { 2, 3 };

    // create MultiSelectList
    ViewBag.FruitSelectList = new MultiSelectList
    (
        items: fruitList,
        dataValueField: nameof(Fruit.FruitId),
        dataTextField: nameof(Fruit.Name),
        selectedValues: selectedFruit
    );

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(DemoViewModel model)
{
    // save model.SelectedFruit to database
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

View:

```
@model DemoViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <select id="fruitSelect" class="form-control" asp-for="SelectedCities" asp-items="ViewBag.FruitSelectList"></select>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#fruitSelect').select2();
        });
    </script>
}
```

And here is a simple [demo project](https://github.com/Jimmys20/SO75948112).